# Does the amount of memory in a GPU influences mining?

Tags: mining-hardware

I am really new to this and am willing to give it a go.
I've seen some rigs online and I would probably go for one, especially if I can upgrade the GPUs.
So, I understand the heavy lifting is done by the GPU, so it's only fair to suppose a 256-bit GPU will do better than a 128-bit. But will the amount of memory make a significant difference?